# Почему метод read() считывает символы через один?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, io

При чтении из файла метод read() считывает символы через один. Независимо от того, используется ли байтовый или символьный поток.

```
do {
r = fi.read(); // считываю символ
if(r != -1) fo.write(r); // записываю его в файл, если не достигнут конец файла
} while (fi.read() != -1) // чтение и запись выполняются, пока не достигнут конец файла
```

Если изменить последнюю строку на

```
while (r != -1)
```

проблема устраняется. 
Какая разница между значением, которое имеет переменная, и тем, которое возвращает метод, ведь оно, получается, одно и то же?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что *каждый*  вызов `read` читает новый символ из файла.

Это значит, что и при проверке в условии `while` символ считывается, но никуда не записывается. Поэтому каждый второй символ - отбрасывается.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, доперло)